# Using c++, write pdf file and open it by Preview app in osx

Tags: c++, macos, applescript

1. Wrote the .pdf file to the disk by using **fopen** and **fwrite**.

   ```
   FILE * fp = fopen("/Users/test/Documents/1.pdf", "w+");
   if (fp) {
       fwrite(pdf_data, size_of_pdf_data, 1, fp);
       fclose(fp);
   }
   ```
2. And then open **1.pdf** within **Preview.app** by using ***applescript***.

   ```
   system("osascript -e \'tell app \"Preview\" to open \"/Users/test/Documents/1.pdf\"");
   ```
3. when the **system** function executes, the file permission issue occurred like the following image:

File Permission Issue

[image: Error message]

How can I fix this issue? I am using **macOS Catalina 10.15.7** and **xcode 11.3.1**.

Comment: First thing to test would be to see if you can open the file yourself, outside of your program.

Comment: Second thing to test would be to follow the instructions you have been given to view or change the file permissions. You cannot solve this problem until you do some investigation to find out what the problem is in the first place.

Comment: Solving problems in computing is usually more complicated than quoting the error message and then applying the magic spell that fixes that particular error.

Comment: First thing: I can open the pdf file outside of this program. e.g. in Finder with double click.

Second thing: I think it is not related with the file permissions. but the permission of the pdf file is rw-rw-rw.

Comment: OK I would try your system command but from the shell. Does that work if you just type in the command manually?

Comment: the system command in terminal failed with the same error.

Comment: I'm wondering about the apple script command. I know nothing about apple script but I wonder is this is a quoting issue, AFAIK the string that you pass to system will get processed first by bash, which is going to have something to say about that single quote. Just a theory

Comment: I think it is not a quoting issue. And the single quote does work well in the terminal.

Comment: Maybe you just need a closing single quote?

Comment: Oh well I'm out of ideas, but at least you know it's not your C++ program at  fault because the same command from the shell also fails.

Comment: To begin with, you need to quote properly; `"osascript -e 'tell app \"Preview\" to open \"/Users/test/Documents/1.pdf\"'"`

Comment: Preview’s `open` command wants a file specifier, so for a posix path use `POSIX file`.

Comment: @red_menace That's not true.  The AppleScript code in and of itself is fine (or, at least, it is now that @molbdnila fixed the quoting).  There's some variability, but many programs' `open` handlers accept plain, posix-formatted file paths (certainly all of Apple's programs do, except for Finder).

Comment: @CJK - I retested with my Monterey system to be sure, but when using only the path string it fails with that permissions dialog in both the Script Editor and via `osascript`, while adding the `POSIX file` command opens the file.  It gets stranger though, because once the file is successfully opened, both work _without_ using `POSIX file` - but change the path/name and it starts over again with the permissions dialog.

Comment: @red_menace I stand corrected.  That is strange, though, as I'm in Monterey but I don't think I've encountered this anomaly before. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @CJK - Actually, I just discovered it when trying to figure out why we were getting different results.  It looks like the "anomaly" (nice) goes back at least as far as Sierra.

Comment: @red_menace Do you know if this has been observed in general ?  I'm wondering whose system setup is the outlier here: yours for exhibiting this phenomenon, or mine for not.  Typically, I would have said yours, purely because what I described above ***ought*** to be true.  However, that you're able to observe this in multiple version of macOS suggests something buggy that perhaps I inadvertently circumvented during setup without knowing. (This sounds like a boast; it's not.  I don't like my system behaving abnormally, even if it's seemingly of benefit.)

Comment: @CJK - It looks like some kind of caching issue with the particular app.  If Preview (also TextEdit) have not opened the file before, using a text path will result in the error dialog - otherwise, the text path works with the Script Editors and `osascript` (although from the scripting dictionary it shouldn’t).  The only reason I came across this weirdness was from your comment, so my guess is that maybe you opened your test file before running the script, while I didn’t.  A lot of apps _will_ open a file using a path string, so it probably just hasn’t been stumbled across that much.

Comment: @red_menace You're probably right.  I'll have a play around with this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppleScript is 100% completely the wrong tool for this job.

Were you in ObjC you’d use `NSWorkspace`. Since you’re in C[++], use LaunchServices’ [LSOpenFromURLSpec](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1441986-lsopenfromurlspec?language=objc).

Comment: I've just solved the problem.
`osascript -e 'do shell script "open /Users/test/Douments/1.pdf"'` worked for me.

Comment: Good grief. `system("open /Users/test/Douments/1.pdf")` if you really must [wooden table](https://what.thedailywtf.com/topic/13134/wooden-table-sighting) it. But you shouldn’t be going through shell at all: that’s an [accident of quoting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells) waiting to happen. If a solution seems excessively convoluted and difficult, it usually is. There are OS APIs for opening files in apps *safely*. Use them. You’ll be a better programmer for it, and your software less likely to explode.